# How to pass stored procedure name from parameter in ExecuteSqlInterpolated method in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a method in which I am calling a stored procedure, but I want to make it dynamic so that whatever stored procedure name I will pass it should use.

Here is sample code in which the stored procedure name is passed as static i.e. UspReportClient

```
public async Task<int> Report(string sStartDate, string sEndDate, string spName)
{
    try
    {
        #region Fetch From DB
        var paramToDt = new SqlParameter("@TODATE", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        paramToDt.Value = sStartDate;

        var paramFrmDt = new SqlParameter("@FROMDATE", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        paramFrmDt.Value = sEndDate;

        var data = await Task.Run(() => _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"EXEC UspReportClient @TODATE={paramToDt},@FROMDATE={paramFrmDt}"));       

        #endregion
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }    
}
```

But instead of hardcoding it, I want to pass in the `spName` parameter to the `Report` method, and from there it should use that stored procedure name.

Comment: Use RawSql where you have a string : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as follows:

```cs
        // Use the spName parameter to specify the stored procedure dynamically
        var data = await Task.Run(() => _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"EXEC {spName} @TODATE={paramToDt}, @FROMDATE={paramFrmDt}"));
```

In this modified code, we use `spName` parameter in the `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` method. Now, you can call the `Report` method and pass the desired stored procedure name as the `spName` parameter, making it dynamic and configurable. You may choose to pass dynamic parameters using `IDictionary<string, object>` in case different SPs may have different input parameters

Comment: While the solution is technically correct and async methods can indeed help when querying a database, using the `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` method to execute a stored procedure can potentially open up serious security vulnerabilities such as SQL injection attacks, especially if the stored procedure name spName or other parameters come from user-supplied inputs. The recommended way to execute a stored procedure in Entity Framework Code First is using the `FromSqlInterpolated` or `FromSqlRaw` methods. But even with those methods, you must always ensure that any parameters are parameterized.

Comment: @LuccaFerri, I totally agree with the views in fact we need to also validate if the object or SP already exists in the database or not.